# Problem with Jquery live-based function

Tags: jquery, function, live

I am currently dynamically adding content to the page with the help of Jquery. The content that is being added contains some input fields and I need to use some kind of form hint/helper plugin on those.

I have tried this one, but i have no idea how to set it up correctly: http://mucur.name/system/jquery_example/ whilst dealing with the neccessity of live event.

Here is a part of my current code that allows me to submit each parent form for each input field.

```
        $(".myclassname").live("keyup", function(){
        $(this).parents("form").submit();
      });
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Well, basically the code i posted works perfect, but how do i make the Jquery form hinting to work on dynamically posted contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1751-jQuery-Live-Method-And-Event-Bubbling.htm) the example of live method of jquery ...

[Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) is the second example..

Comment: Thanks! Turned out that the plugin Livequery was what i were looking for!